# How to convert HTML to RTF and vice versa in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I am working on RichEditBox Control in Windows 10 UWP to allow a user with some formatting options.I am getting a HTML from the server and I want to convert that into RTF to display it in RichEditBox. Similarly, I want to convert it again to HTML when the user has completed editing. I did a search but I got samples but they are not helping. One of them that I found is working for RichTextBlock, not RichEditBox

[HTML to RTF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Html-to-RTF-a757fac5)

I also tried below URL(RTF to HTML) but it doesn't give proper output

[RTF to HTML](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2006/10/20/writing-an-rtf-to-html-converter-posting-code-in-blogs/)

Please, someone, suggest how to achieve my requirement with RichEditBox as it is only control that allows formatting options as Bold,Italic,Bullet points etc.

Comment: If you have money for a 3rd party library it would be trivial. Search for document convertors.

Comment: Can you suggest some?

Comment: I've only used [text control](www.textcontrol.com/html5) but that is much more than a converter. Look at Aspose, gnostice

Comment: Will check,but I don't to pay for this.

Comment: @Kinjan I am also in same situation, have you got any converters? or any solutions for this?

Comment: @Noorul No I have to keep this feature on hold as I didn't found any converter. If you find something let me know.

Comment: Sure , I am still trying to get the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Noorul Microsoft should provide some easy conversion for this in coming SDK update, what you say?

Comment: @kinjan yes of course, there must me some inbuilt method with in the RichEditBox itself, to convert that RTF to possible most used formats like HTML.

Comment: @Noorul, I checked it in past and there is no inbuilt method function available for conversion.

Comment: sorry, What mean to say is, its really needed to have a inbuilt method, but none is available currently . Even i also tried a lot.Now I got a converter in WPF, trying to use it in UWP. Lets c.....

Comment: @Noorul If it works for you, please post it as answer, I will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: ya, sure. But am really struggling a lot to find the missing library's . Lot of changes happened between WPF and UWP. Let me give a try , hope for good.

Comment: @Noorul Best of luck... :-)

Comment: @Noorul Did you succeed in converting RTF to HTML in UWP?

Comment: Hi Kinjan, I have got a convertion method which i modified a little, it is converting for text formats . But i didn't analysed the scenario with Image. Anyway i will post the answer.

Comment: @Noorul Yes please post it. Is it converting RTF to HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the base concept to convert in [this link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/RTF-TO-HTML-in-Metro-Style-08646375) , and I created the following method to convert rtf to html . it converts the text format options correctly.

Here is the method which converts rtf to html , u can edit as per ur need

```
 public static string ConvertToHtml(RichEditBox richEditBox)
    {
        string text, strColour, strFntName, strHTML;
        richEditBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out text);
        ITextRange txtRange = richEditBox.Document.GetRange(0, text.Length);
        strHTML = "<html>";

        int lngOriginalStart = txtRange.StartPosition;
        int lngOriginalLength = txtRange.EndPosition;
        float shtSize = 11;

        // txtRange.SetRange(txtRange.StartPosition, txtRange.EndPosition);

        bool bOpened = false, liOpened = false, numbLiOpened = false, iOpened = false, uOpened = false, bulletOpened = false, numberingOpened = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            txtRange.SetRange(i, i + 1);

            if (i == 0)
            {
                strColour = txtRange.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor.ToString();
                shtSize = txtRange.CharacterFormat.Size;
                strFntName = txtRange.CharacterFormat.Name;
                strHTML += "<span style=\"font-family:" + strFntName + "; font-size: " + shtSize + "pt; color: #" + strColour.Substring(3) + "\">";
            }


            if (txtRange.CharacterFormat.Size != shtSize)
            {
                shtSize = txtRange.CharacterFormat.Size;
                strHTML += "</span><span style=\"font-family: " + txtRange.CharacterFormat.Name + "; font-size: " + txtRange.CharacterFormat.Size + "pt; color: #" + txtRange.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor.ToString().Substring(3) + "\">";
            }

            if (txtRange.Character == Convert.ToChar(13))
            {
                strHTML += "<br/>";
            }

            #region bullet
            if (txtRange.ParagraphFormat.ListType == MarkerType.Bullet)
            {
                if (!bulletOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "<ul>";
                    bulletOpened = true;
                }

                if (!liOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "<li>";
                    liOpened = true;
                }

                if (txtRange.Character == Convert.ToChar(13))
                {
                    strHTML += "</li>";
                    liOpened = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (bulletOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "</ul>";
                    bulletOpened = false;
                }
            }

            #endregion

            #region numbering
            if (txtRange.ParagraphFormat.ListType == MarkerType.LowercaseRoman)
            {
                if (!numberingOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "<ol type=\"i\">";
                    numberingOpened = true;
                }

                if (!numbLiOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "<li>";
                    numbLiOpened = true;
                }

                if (txtRange.Character == Convert.ToChar(13))
                {
                    strHTML += "</li>";
                    numbLiOpened = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (numberingOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "</ol>";
                    numberingOpened = false;
                }
            }

            #endregion

            #region bold
            if (txtRange.CharacterFormat.Bold == FormatEffect.On)
            {
                if (!bOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "<b>";
                    bOpened = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (bOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "</b>";
                    bOpened = false;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region italic
            if (txtRange.CharacterFormat.Italic == FormatEffect.On)
            {
                if (!iOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "<i>";
                    iOpened = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (iOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "</i>";
                    iOpened = false;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region underline
            if (txtRange.CharacterFormat.Underline == UnderlineType.Single)
            {
                if (!uOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "<u>";
                    uOpened = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (uOpened)
                {
                    strHTML += "</u>";
                    uOpened = false;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            strHTML += txtRange.Character;
        }


        strHTML += "</span></html>";

        return strHTML;
    }
```

And I am yet to start the reverse conversion for html to rtf, once i done with that, i will post that answer too.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Noorul.

Comment: Thanks. Will surely give it a try.

Comment: No but will try and if it works will mark answer as accepted. Also, how to handle bullet points and nymbers list? Did you tried that?

Comment: Yes , I forget to inform that. Even i got stuck in there, There is no conversion for bullet points, currently i am going forward with this simple conversion, since I need to complete it soon. Later i will add the conversion for bullet points too, and will edit the answer.

Comment: If you got any better solution pls update it here :)

Comment: Hi Kinjan, I updated the answer for bullet and numbering too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did you checked my other question, if you can help me with that?

Comment: Yes I checked, am not that much familiar with those concepts.I regret that I can't help you in that.:(

Comment: This works fine. But I want to remove `<span style="font-family:Segoe UI; font-size: 12pt; color: #000000">` which is added during conversion. Is it possible?

Comment: yes , u can. it gives the style options. if you remove that u need to add some alternate for that, or go without style options.

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm

Comment: @Noorul To help others, you may want to add a line in your original post that states that your solution covers the features of converting of the bullets and numbering, as well. I had first ignored your solution after reading a comment from a user that it does not cover bullets and numbering. But then I had to go through all the comments of this post to later discover that you indeed cover those two features as well.