# How to show html format using RichTextBlock

Tags: uwp, richtextblock

I am currently working on Windows 10 UWP project. I am getting a HTML file from the server and I want show this in UWP app.I want to use RichTextBlock instead of web view.I tried github code [here](https://github.com/xleon/HTML2XAML) which has used Html2Xaml library but I'm getting error when I try to bind data to RichTextBlock.I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936114/how-to-convert-html-to-rtf-and-vice-versa-in-windows-10-uwp) but it only contains to convert rtf to html

I just simply want to convert html to the RichTextBlock and show the html file in UWP app.Please, someone, suggest how to achieve my requirement with RichTextBlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to display Html is to use `WebView`, but if you want to convert it into text that `RichTextBlock` can display, this may be more complicated.

Let me briefly explain the idea:

**1. Load Html and turn it into a parseable entity.**

In the nuget package manager, you can find some related Html parsing packages, search `Html` to download the most popular package.

**2. Parse the Html document and generate the corresponding `Block` or `Inline` based on the tag type by recursion**

The recursive method is to check whether the `Tag` currently being parsed has children, and if so, repeat the parse method.

**3. Write conversion methods for various tags**

`RichTextBlock` cannot be converted into corresponding styled text according to Html tags, so this needs to be written by ourselves.

Take `<b> ... </b>` as an example, this is a bold inline text. You can use this method when converting:

```cs
private static Inline GenerateBold(HtmlNode node)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText.Trim()))
        return null;
    Span s = new Span();
    s.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = node.InnerText.Trim(), FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
    return s;
}
```

The text types supported by `RichTextBlock` are under the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents` namespace, which are mainly divided into `Inline` and `Block`. If you want to see all the text types in this namespace, you can view this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents)

---

Converting Html tags to text types supported by `RichTextBlock` requires one-to-one conversion. In addition, you may not be able to fully reproduce the effect of CSS on styles in `RichTextBlock` (this means that you also need to build a CSS parser).

If you are going to do this great job, I hope my suggestions can help you.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.And If I write conversion method how can I bind It to the richtextblock from xaml file.I have tried it once like this   <RichTextBlock converter:HtmlProperties="{Binding HtmlString}" Grid.Row="0"/> .This HtmlProperties is class name of converter method.But it gives error saying The property "HtmlProperties" does not exist in the "using XAMLHtml" namespace

Comment: Hello, do you have a demo that can be reproduced? `converter:HtmlProperties` should be a dependency property you wrote yourself, I don't know how it is implemented. But if it was me, I might generate a `List<Block>` based on the tags after parsing the Html, and then add entries to `RichTextBlock.Blocks`

Comment: I asked question regarding that issue in here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073947/how-to-convert-html-to-rtf-in-uwp.This includes the code that I used to convert.I'm new to UWP and not good with these stuff yet

Comment: Hi, I looked at your code in the question, you defined the `Html` property, but you did not implement the `SetHtml` and `GetHtml` methods, which is why your custom dependency properties are not recognized. Please check the solution of Nico Zhu in the question. In the `MainPage.xaml.cs` of his solution, there is a `Properties` class, which has the implementation of `GetHtml` and `SetHtml`.